# Passport.js login for one request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to add a feature that will let me specify a user ID to log in as via a header when in development mode, so that I can develop API endpoints more easily. I have the login-via-header working, but the problem is that the login session persists for other requests after that, even if I'm not using the header (I'm not even sending Cookie--not sure how Passport is persisting the session [EDIT: my bad, I was sending Cookies, I was just using Postman and it didn't show `Cookie` in the request headers, but it was sending it nevertheless]). I would like to have the login apply for the duration of the request and no longer.

I tried calling `req.logout()` in an event handler for the `finish`/`close` event on `res`, and the logout is getting called, but subsequent requests still have `req.user`.

Is there a good way to provide a request-long login?

Comment: Don't use sessions, ie. set `{session: false}` in `passport.authenticate`? http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate#disable-sessions

Comment: I don't use `passport.authenticate()` though, I use `passport.login(userObj)`. If I'm not mistaken, `passport.authenticate()` triggers the whole strategy process (e.g. if I'm using Facebook strategy, it'll go through the whole fetching a token from FB, etc.). I can get the user object from the DB, I just want to authenticate it through Passport.

Comment: You mean `req.login`? Or is there really `passport.login`? Couldn't find it in the code. Anyways, I think `authenticate` is what you should do anyways even if you have the token in the header using eg. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant `req.login()`. Why would that be the better way? It seems like a lot to add an additional dependency and auth strategy just for a dev convenience.

Comment: Well mainly just because that's how passport works, and I believe you would just need to use your existing header authentication code in the strategy callback. But, try passing [`{session: false}` then to the `login` call](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/6e37662f5f4931c9189d4f31eb3f2a8a76f66a83/lib/http/request.js#L42)

Comment: @vesse that worked! thanks! I didn't see that option in the docs somehow. If you put that in an answer, I'll mark it as selected.